# Empty $_POST data

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I am trying to post a post to my MyBB server from a Python script, but try as I might, I can't get it to work. The request shows up in the forensic log and the headers are in the `$_SERVER` variable, but `$_POST` is always an empty array. The error log shows nothing, even at the debug level. I've already tried searching, but I haven't found anything that's helped. I already checked the post_max_size thing, which is 8M.

Another factor is that it's just my own requests which aren't going through. Browser generated requests seem to do just fine. I've looked and looked, but I can't find anything I'm doing differently that should matter.

Anyway, here is an example request.

```
POST /newreply.php?tid=1&processed=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: <redacted>
Accept-Encoding: identity
Content-Length: 1153
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-->0xa216654L
Cookie: sid=<redacted>; mybb[lastvisit]=1354995469; mybb[lastactive]=1354995500; mybb[threadread]=a%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A1%3Bi%3A1354995469%3B%7D; mybb[forumread]=a%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A2%3Bi%3A1354995469%3B%7D; loginattempts=1; mybbuser=2_ZlVVfaYS9FstZGQzr4KiNRUm3Z4xAgJkTPPq2ouFcuaragOTVQ
Accept: text/html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1

-->0xa216654L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="my_post_key"

257b2bbef4334000d9088169154900a3
-->0xa216654L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="quoted_ids"


-->0xa216654L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tid"

1
-->0xa216654L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"

foo!2
-->0xa216654L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachmentact"


-->0xa216654L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachmentaid"


-->0xa216654L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="icon"

-1
-->0xa216654L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="posthash"

e93a2c78ce3f6807a86fd475ef4178cf
-->0xa216654L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="postoptions[subscriptionmethod]"


-->0xa216654L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="replyto"


-->0xa216654L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message_new"

foo!2
-->0xa216654L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

Post Reply
-->0xa216654L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-->0xa216654L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"

do_newreply
-->0xa216654L
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

Lol
-->0xa216654L
```

Comment: This sound more like a Python. programming question regarding usage of urllib and others. Also, it would be nice to see more details how you generated that request and whether it's a request known to work or not.

Comment: Well whether the request is valid or not has nothing to do with how it was generated. So I thought the Python part was irrelevant. Anyway, I can post an example of a browser request that worked for comparison if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. You need to prepend two dashes to the boundary token, except for the instance in the Content-Type header. Also, you need to append two dashes to the final boundary. Funny how nothing I've read has ever mentioned this.

Comment: You must not have read [the RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1521#section-7.2), then. :)

Comment: You're right. I assumed my book would mention something important like that.